# Python is searching in the wrong user folder

Tags: python, c#, .net

I am running a python script with `Process.Start` from c#. The program works correctly on my main PC however when I try to run it on another computer it comes up with this error:

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\[User name on main Pc ]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: What version of python are you using?  Older versions the filename (including path) is limited to around 128 characters.

Comment: @jdweng I have 3.8 and 3.9 installed

Comment: The code cannot find the python executable 3.8.  Is it installed or are you referencing the wrong version.   It is looking for the python in the use path.  Did you install as single user or for all users?  Which user did you install python?

Comment: Now that you mention it I have actually not installed python for all users. I'll try that as soon as I get back to my pc.

Comment: I installed python again but it's looking for it in the wrong folder. For example. My user folder's name on my main pc from where I copied the files via Github is John, and the one I am copying to is Jane. The program is looking for a python file in the user folder called John on both computers

Comment: Open solution explorer and check the reference for python.  You can right click and change name/location.  You can also open the csproj file with Notepad and make the change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python is not installed on the other PC. That's why your script is not working. You need to install Python first, so your PC is able to interpret your code.

Comment: I installed python again but it's looking for it in the wrong folder. For example. My user folder's name on my main pc from where I copied the files via Github is John, and the one I am copying to is Jane. The program is looking for a python file in the user folder called `John` on both computers.